# Add on of user defined object (UDO) is connected successfully but not found in SAP B1 9.2

Tags: sdk, sapb1

May you explain me the reason why my add on is not found in SAP B1 please? I created user defined object (UDO) called membership, Parent Menu ID is in Human Resources module, so after registering UDO(membership) I created an addon where I used SAP B1 studio for additional fields and then I used MS Visual studio for SAP B1 to package files. I registered .ard file and start addon successfully but the problem is I don't find my addon in SAP B1 9.2, if I click membership in Human Resources it opens UDO membership form not membership form of addon.

How can I solve this problem?

Please anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

By default SAP Business One will have newly Add-Ons "Disabled" in the start-up options. Check the Add-On Administration screen to make sure your add-on is set to start-up Automatically.

Comment: Yes I did it Overhed, it is set to start-up Automatically. Actually I create an add-on of system form (for example Employee Master Data) it works correctly where I go In Human Resources module and click Employee Master Data and then add-on form is opened. But I do know where form of add-on of UDO will be displayed in SAP B1 module. I set UDO in Human Resources module (called Membership) but even if my add-on is stared if I click Membership form it opens Membership form of UDO not the Membership form of add-on. Actually, where add-ons of UDO are located in SAP B1 modules?

Comment: Add-on is connected successfully but I don't find its form in SAP B1 modules.

Comment: Hi all, I used the following codes in Menu.vb in order to find new module and its form but the new form located in the new module is also opening the form of UDO not form of add-on.   If (pVal.BeforeAction And pVal.MenuUID = "mm10.Form1") Then
                    Application.SBO_Application.Menus.Item("MMS").Activate()
                End If